# Pandas json normalize an object property containing an array of objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have json data formatted like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 878787,
      "name": "Testing",
      "schema": {
        "id": 3463463,
        "smartElements": [
          {
            "svKey": "Model",
            "value": {
              "type": "type1",
              "value": "ThisValue"
            }
          },
          {
            "svKey": "SecondKey",
            "value": {
              "type": "example",
              "value": "ThisValue2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 333,
      "name": "NameName",
      "schema": {
        "id": 1111,
        "smartElements": [
          {
            "svKey": "Model",
            "value": {
              "type": "type1",
              "value": "NewValue"
            }
          },
          {
            "svKey": "SecondKey",
            "value": {
              "type": "example",
              "value": "ValueIs"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

is there a way to normalize it so I end up with records:

```
name          Model          SecondKey        
Testing       ThisValue      ThisValue2
NameName      NewValue       ValueIs
```

I can get the smartElements to a pandas series but I can't figure out a way to break out **`smartElements[x].svKey`** to a column header and **`smartElements[x].value.value`** to the value for that column and/or merge it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd skip trying to use a pre-baked solution and just navigate the `json` yourself.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.load(open('my.json'))

records = []
for d in data['result']:
    record = {}
    record['name'] = d['name']
    for ele in d['schema']['smartElements']:
        record[ele['svKey']] = ele['value']['value']
    records.append(record)

pd.DataFrame(records)

       name      Model   SecondKey
0   Testing  ThisValue  ThisValue2
1  NameName   NewValue     ValueIs
```

Comment: I think you're right. I've wasted enough time trying to figure out a solution to fit a problem I don't really have.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
   a = json.load(f)
d = pd.json_normalize(data=a['result'], errors='ignore', record_path=['schema', 'smartElements'], meta=['name'])

print(d)
```

produces

```
       svKey value.type value.value      name
0      Model      type1   ThisValue   Testing
1  SecondKey    example  ThisValue2   Testing
2      Model      type1    NewValue  NameName
3  SecondKey    example     ValueIs  NameName
```

Comment: I feel like `json_normalize` is this super powerful tool that I never have the patience to figure out properly.

Comment: I think a little bit of practice and docs and you will be guru))

Comment: that's close to what I was looking for, but I was hoping to have every svKey as a column with the value.value under it. thank you